# Hex editor for open drives

Tags: drive, editing

There is any good hex editors that can open a *drive* not just a single file? Something like Hex Workshop? I'm looking for something for my Computer Forensics class.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that wxHexEditor fits your needs.

> wxHexEditor is not an ordinary hex editor, but could work as low level
>   disk editor too. If you have problems with your HDD or partition, you
>   can recover your data from HDD or from partition via editing sectors
>   in raw hex. You can edit your partition tables or you could recover
>   files from File System by hand with help of wxHexEditor. Or you might
>   want to analyze your big binary files, partitions, devices... If you
>   need a good reverse engineer tool like a good hex editor, you welcome.
>   wxHexEditor could edit HDD/SDD disk devices or partitions in raw up to
>   exabyte sizes.

You can install it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install wxhexeditor
```

Official webpage: http://www.wxhexeditor.org/

Answer (score 0):

LDE - The linux disk editor, but it works mainly on Ext2/Ext3 and its using is little bit